# How to understand the usage of 'one' in "out of the company of one Hermione Granger"

Tags: word-usage

> Harry has at last found love at Hogwarts. His close friend, Colin Creevey, says that Harry is rarely seen *out of the company of **one** Hermione Granger*, a stunningly pretty Muggle-born girl who, like Harry, is one of the top students in the school.

It seems to me that "*out of the company of Hermione Granger*" is fine. I'm not sure what '**one**' is doing there. Any thought?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good question.  A synonymous phrase for **one** there would be **a certain**:

"... rarely seen out of the company of a certain "Hermione Granger".

You can understand the word **one** and the phrase **a certain** there as meaning "a particular": in the company of a particular person who goes by the name "X" or who can be identified as "X".

It's the sort of phrase you'd encounter in a newspaper gossip column:

> His passions are poker, craps, and nights in the company of a certain redheaded showgirl at the MGM Grand.
>
> The senator was seen in the company of one Luna Walker, a former burlesque dancer at the Trocadero.

or in an [evidentiary proceeding](https://books.google.com/books?id=PhtEAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA260&dq=%22in%20the%20company%20of%20one%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiMvuj03KbfAhWDmuAKHTLWBEA4FBDoAQhWMAg#v=onepage&q=%22in%20the%20company%20of%20one%22&f=false) where things are being stated "for the record".

See also [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=g5VUAAAAcAAJ&pg=PR15&dq=%22in%20the%20company%20of%20one%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiF9eqL3qbfAhUKLa0KHV0dBIk4UBDoAQiWATAT#v=onepage&q=%22in%20the%20company%20of%20one%22&f=false) and [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=DbVCAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA1501&dq=%22in%20the%20company%20of%20one%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi616v03qbfAhWQyIMKHTfaBaQ4eBDoAQgvMAE#v=onepage&q=%22in%20the%20company%20of%20one%22&f=false).

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit formal usage, but it’s pretty standard: it means that the named person will not be previously known to the reader.

I might write to you, for example, and say that I visited Hollywood and met Arnold Schwarzenegger, and also had a fascinating chat with one Aaron Smith whom I met on a park bench. In the first case I’m assuming you know of that person; in the second, this is the first you’ve heard of them.

In informal speech you’d say “a person by the name of” or “a guy called”.